# cmake & Qt5: qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as XXX but QtCore could not be found there

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, cmake, qt5

I'm new to cmake, so having trouble building QCA on Ubuntu 12.04.

I get the following when I run "cmake ." in the cloned QCA repository:

> Blockquote
>   CMake Warning at /home/plunify/qt/cmake-2.8.12.1-Linux-i386/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:659 (message):
>     /opt/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake reported QT_INSTALL_LIBS as
>     "/opt/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib" but QtCore could not be found there.  Qt is NOT
>     installed correctly for the target build environment.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:50 (find_package)

I notice that it is still trying to use FindQt4, however I'm trying to build against Qt5.

I downloaded the latest CMAKE (v2.8.12.1) to make sure it supports Qt5, and I'm also sure QCA (cloned from git clone git://anongit.kde.org/qca.git) supports Qt5 as I've built the same repository successfully against Qt 5.1.1 on Windows (where I just built directly from within Qt Creator).

I've tried all the suggestions of related posts on Stack Overflow but none are working for me.

Any ideas on how to fix it will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok fixed it by adding the following to the top of the Makelists.txt file in the QCA directory:

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/opt/Qt/5.1.0/gcc_64")
```

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: Set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH in your environment to be more-elegant.